# Dual Boot older Toshiba Satelite laptop

Tags: dual-boot, pop-os, refind

I have installed PopOS on a number of laptops but this one is just giving me fits.
Current patient:
Toshiba E45t-B4106
Intel Core I5-5200U
8GB Ram, 1TB HDD
Windows 10 now adding Pop_OS 22.04 LTS

I have come across the new 1GB requirement for a /boot partition and just made a new partition in free space and it just works.  Generally I add REFIND to handle the dual boot.

So this one - REFIND is complaining that:
The ESP doesn't seem to be mounted"...  Must be VFAT - Aborting...

I notice now that the new installer is making the new boot partition EXT4...  Is that part of the problem?  There is no way to convince it to make that partition FAT32.

Grub OS prober is not locating Windows. So even keeping GRUB doesn't really solve my problem.

Inside Bios settings - there is no setting to set which partition I want the boot from - so now stuck not able to get into Windows...

I think this has to do with the current patient being MBR setup vs GPT?  But now I am typing way over my head...

Really not sure what to search for or try at this point too.

Any thoughts, tips or solutions are appreciated.

Comment: Okay - so it seems there is a BIG difference between GPT and MBR disks...  So starting to think that I might need to keep Grub?

If that is so - help me fix my Grub 
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/DrqTFKKXYy/

I know that you are not supposed to edit Grub directly - but how wrong is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! I rolled back your recent edit tagging the title with "SOLVED". Accepting an answer will mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Booted a couple more times and updated Grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

A couple more times and OS prober eventually found Windows 10 and everything started working.  Not sure why it wasn’t doing things right before – but this is solved.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, both MBR and GPT can be used with Linux in either BIOS (Legacy/CSM) or UEFI modes. But AFAIK Windows sticks to MBR+Legacy and GPT+UEFI convention. [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) is strictly EFI based and although not a requirement for dual booting, is indeed easy to use especially when firmware (a.k.a. BIOS) lets entering custom .efi file paths, since it lists any .efi entry on any disk it can reach by default (unlike GRUB).

Secondly, boot partition (`/boot`) stores the bootloader config (e.g. /boot/grub/grub.cfg) and kernels (e.g /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.15-201...). Whereas, ESP ([EFI System Partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition)) (`/boot/efi`) stores .efi files (e.g. /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI). ESP must strictly be in FAT format and is a requirement for booting in EFI mode regardles of boot partition.

Thirdly, the boot partition is not always a requirement but is nice to have. If the root partition (`/`) can be readily driven while booting, then kernel can be stored (under a directory) in it. AFAIK, EFI drivers support ext and xfs, however, there is not a viable driver for LVM nor ZFS yet (word of mouth, better read on it if interested). So one would create an ext2/ext3/ext4 or xfs partition for boot and rely on kernel modules (drivers) onwards for loading the root partition. I guess this is a bit more in depth than required, but is the overview of partitions of the boot process.

Other directories were historically on their own partitions, and some still do separate them. Most common one is `/home`, generally where user data is stored, I would go for a single `/` as a rookie though.

Now, for your problem to be MBR related, your Windows 10 installation would require to be in Legacy mode, and I doubt that as it is not the default.

(I assume your disk is /dev/sdX, for instance /dev/sda)
For Windows 10, ESP is the /dev/sdX1 (VFAT and 100MiB in size) and should store {refind, , Microsoft} directories according to your explanation. I have no idea why rEFInd would error that out, unless you tried to install it on boot partition as /dev/sdX1 (1GB) and it somehow got booted. I sincerely do not know, as you have successfully booted Windows at some point, so you must have not deleted existing ESP.

For future reference defaults file for GRUB (/etc/default/grub) [should have OS prober enabled](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373194/os-prober-and-update-grub-find-windows-install-yet-it-does-not-show-in-boot-men). Might need more options for booting up from mutiple disks

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
```

Extra: While at it, here is how to [boot last selected entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148662/how-to-get-grub2-to-remember-last-choice) each boot up:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

Then apply changes with `update-grub` or more generally `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` (might need grub2 rather than grub)

This is unfortunately not an answer per se, yet hopefully keeps your kindle going.

Comment: Hey thanks for this - I ended up somehow getting through the problems I was having.  Os_prober eventually worked and found Windows10 so I just kept rolling with that.  I can't say that I understand everything - but it is working so I just went with that.